# EF Code First - Seeding Data Order Changes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am wondering why when seeding data in EF Code First, it ends up in the database in a different (random) order to how its added to the context.

Say I have some category data and watching the context.Categories.Local during seeding I can see it is in this order:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3
- Category 4

However, after the code runs it ends up in the database something like

- Category 3
- Category 2
- Category 4
- Category 1

What would make it change? And is there anyway to keep it in a certain order?

**Edit**:
Order is not random. It only changes order when there is a relationship. i.e. only some Categories have questions linked to them. Looks as though EF inserts records with questions first.

```
 new Category()
            {
                Name = "Category 1",
                CategoryQuestions = new List<CategoryQuestion>() {
                    new CategoryQuestion() {Question = "Question 1"},
                    new CategoryQuestion() {Question = "Question 2"}
                }
            }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is that really important? I wonder why. If you want the category name to be ordered as you want you can put index on category name column on your database.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, no not really important and doesnt affect my program, just wondering how EF is doing the insert that it becomes random. Would think it would just insert in the order it gets it.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is not random. It only changes order when there is a relationship and only some models are linked. i.e. only some Categories have questions linked to them. Looks as though EF inserts records with questions first.

```
new List<Category>() {
    new Category()
    {
        Name = "Category 1"
    },
    new Category()
    {
        Name = "Category 2",
        CategoryQuestions = new List<CategoryQuestion>() {
           new CategoryQuestion() {Question = "Question 1"},
           new CategoryQuestion() {Question = "Question 2"}
        }
    }
}
```

Category 2 will appear first in database.